# sql query to filter for column value that occurs over the course of two dates with one specific condition met one day and another the next

Tags: mysql, sql, databricks

Trying to find a way to query merchants that appear in a table yesterday with an x tag and then appear again in the same table with a y tag the next day (today).

| merchant | date | tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Target | 2023-02-09 | x |
| Target | 2023-02-10 | y |

I just want a query that will find examples like the one above and return all merchants that meet the criteria. Originally the x and y tags are from different tables and I brought them together with a union, but I'm a little stuck trying to find a good solution to pull out what I need from the temp table.

Comment: Can you share what final output are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you pretty close. A self join that limits the records in the where clause by date and then by tag.

```
    SELECT Tdays.Merchant, 
        Tdays.date, 
        Tdays.tag, 
        Ydays.date, 
        ydays.tag
    FROM tblMerchants AS Ydays INNER JOIN
        tblMerchants AS Tdays ON Tdays.Merchant = Ydays.Merchant
    WHERE (Tdays.date = getDate() AND Tdays.tag = 'x') AND 
        (Ydays.date = DATEADD(day, -1, getDate()) AND Ydays.tag = 'Y')
```